# Why can't twistd import a module from it's current working directory?

Tags: python, path, twistd

Please consider the following test case.

The project directory is structured thusly:

```
foo
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── bar.py
└── test.tac
```

`bar.py` contains a trivial class definition:

```
# bar.py
class Bar:
    pass
```

`test.tac`, the Twisted Application Configuration file, contains a single import statement:

```
#test.tac
from foo.bar import Bar
```

When running `twistd -ny test.tac`, I obtain the following error:

```
$ twistd -ny test.tac
Unhandled Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 674, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 25, in runApp
    runner.run()
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 381, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 453, in createOrGetApplication
    application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/app.py", line 464, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/application/service.py", line 416, in loadApplication
    application = sob.loadValueFromFile(filename, 'application')
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 177, in loadValueFromFile
    eval(codeObj, d, d)
  File "test.tac", line 1, in <module>
    from foo.bar import Bar
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'


Failed to load application: No module named 'foo'
```

This is very surprising because `python test.tac` produces no error.  In order to further debug, I modified `test.tac` as follows:

```
from sys import path
print(path)
from foo.bar import Bar
```

This revealed that running `python <filename>` prepends the current working directory to the path whereas running `twistd <filename>` does not.

### My question is twofold:

1. Is this a bug, or is there a good reason for `twistd` to behave this way?
2. What is the recommended way of fixing this in `twistd`.  Is there some sort of option I can set or does it need to be done manually?

Answer (score 1):

this snippet will add directory containing the tac file to python path

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

from foo.bar import Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no rule in Python saying the working directory should be on the path. Rather, by default, Python puts the directory of the *main script* on the path. When you run `python test.tac`, that directory is the working directory, but when you run twistd, the main Python script is some part of Twisted, which does not lie in the working directory.

As I am unfamiliar with Twisted, I cannot say what combination of code organization and Twisted configuration you're supposed to use to make this import work.